# Does someone use Django-Socialauth successful 

Tags: python, django, openid, django-socialauth

I am using [Django-Socialauth](https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) , my site is [here](http://zjm1126.alwaysdata.net/accounts/login/?next=/)

But I'm not successful now, I think `Django-Socialauth`  lacks a method that get user data from `openid_response`.

Can anyone give me successful demo about it?

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Django-Socialauth, but the same functionality is offered by a package with a similar name called:

django-social-auth

which I find to be very well documented.

You can find it here: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

You can find documentation and examples here:

http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: +1, That rather subtle distinction between the two projects is worth noting.