# Does anyone support openid successfully on django site , which solutions did you use 

Tags: python, django, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does someone  use Django-Socialauth  successful .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476492/does-someone-use-django-socialauth-successful)

i am using [Django-Socialauth](https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) , my site is [here](http://zjm1126.alwaysdata.net/)

but i am not seccessful now using it ,

so what solutions did you use if support openid successfully  on your django site  .

thanks

Comment: I'm looking at https://github.com/simonw/django-openid

Comment: why post a new question instead of changing the first?

Comment: Because new questions attract more new people, and different people. It's been proven time and time again, that posting a new question, is more effective and quicker to getting a correct answer than editing an existing question.